# Error configuring Google Apps Email in Redmine 1.1.2

Tags: email, redmine

I have configured my email.yml in my Redmine installation, but when I try to send a test email, I get the following error message.

```
An error occurred while sending mail (%{value})
```

Here is a dump of my email.yml excluding the password details.

```
production:
  delivery_method: :smtp
  smtp_settings:
    address: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    domain: <domain>.com
    authentication: :login
    user_name: "redmine@<domain>.com"
    password: "<password>"
```

I am trying to configure Redmine instance to use google apps email service. 
PS: I have also installed smtp_tls in the lib folder of my installation using the following command

```
curl -O http://blog.expandrive.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/smtp_tls.rb
```

Also, in my config/environments/production.rb file, I have included

```
require "smtp_tls"
```

Any help is appreciated. I was expecting some error message in place of %{value} so not really sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the steps outlined at http://redmineblog.com/articles/setup-redmine-to-send-email-using-gmail/? That is what I've been using for years now with no problems. Some other users have shared their own configurations and results in the comments.

Comment: I have.. but same result. I don't know if its a problem with my email.yml or something else..

Comment: Fixed it.. just had to upgrade to 1.2-stable.. and that fixed it. Some locale issue in that version I think..